# How to create a LinearLayout with TextView and Image on each row to fill up screen height

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to achieve  the below layout in my Android Application.

[image]

I achieved this layout by using a custom List Adapter. But the problem is with the empty space in the bottom. Is it possible to make the ListView items be evenly spaced to occupy the entire screen height.

One alternative is to use LinearLayout with WeightSum. But with this approach, how will I be able to place textView and the arrow image in the same row.

Any suggestion to achieve this layout and evenly distribute row height would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

**Main Activity XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/startscreen_background"
    tools:context=".StartScreen" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/start_lv_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="@color/startscreen_listitem_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="0px" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**List Item Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startscreen_tv_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/startscreen_listitem_height"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/startscreen_listitem_paddingleft"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/startscreen_listitem_textcolor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/startscreen_listitem_textsize" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px"
        android:background="@color/startscreen_listitem_divider" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You want each row to expand itself vertically so that the entire view fits the height of the ListView?

Comment: @ramaral: I have updated the Question with Layouts..

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16405979/2556111)

Comment: @ramaral: But I would like to achieve this in XML layout, instead of the class.. Please provide any reference to such an example.. Appreciate your help so far.. :-)

Comment: @RickFalck: Either way would do.. I would prefer XML layouts to Code based..

Comment: @SriHari use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` and use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for your image

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in your **Main Activity XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/startscreen_background"
tools:context=".StartScreen" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/start_lv_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="@color/startscreen_listitem_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="0px" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried giving the `layout_height="match_parent"` to your ListView ?