# ListView (height) inside DrawerLayout doesn't fill the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I use a `ListView` as **NavigationView** inside a custom `DrawerLayout` but when I removed some Items from the `ListView`this later doesn't fill the screen.

## Screenshot

[image]

## Layout.xml

```
<ma.www.helpers.HackyDrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="15">

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments Act/Profe/Rechercher -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="9"/>
        <!-- Framelayout to display menu-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6">

            <GridView
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:id="@+id/gridView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="fill" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
        android:divider="#ce2580"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
</ma.www.helpers.HackyDrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by either of the two ways:
1. Use relativelayout instead of linearlayout.
2. Adjust the first list so that it fills the full row is occupied.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML markup, you are setting the `layout_width` to `250dp`, try changing it to `fill_parent` or `match_parent`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
    android:divider="#ce2580"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```

**EDIT:**
As per your edits, please see this post: [Android List view fill the height to the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405690/android-list-view-fill-the-height-to-the-contents)
They suggest using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `ListView`, given that you have a fixed number of items.

Comment: I have problem with the  `height` property

Comment: Oh, right. Well, that's how `ListView` works, it won't space out all the items to fill the `height`. I'm not sure if it's possible to fill the `height`, unless you used a custom `Adapter`, I think.

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405690/android-list-view-fill-the-height-to-the-contents. They suggest using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `ListView`, given that you have a fixed number of items.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ListView like that,

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_scroll_style"
        android:divider="#ce2580"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```